# Low stock message on woocommerce for certain category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I have changed the text for the "low stock" message in my WooCommerce store, but I sell tiles and the message currently says "Only X m2 left in stock". I want to change the text for certain categories or products that do not sell by square meters, but instead by just meters. How can I achieve this?

I have searched extensively online but couldn't find a solution or properly formulate my question. I came across a similar question, but I'm not sure how to modify the low-stock message for specific cases. Also, I am not using the Oceanwp theme.

Here is the code I found that allows me to modify the out-of-stock text:

```
function my_woo_outofstock_text( $text ) {
    global $product;
    
    // Add categories. Multiple can be added, separated by a comma
    $specific_categories = array( 'original-paintings' );
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // NOT in stock & has term
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && has_term( $specific_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            $text = __( 'Sold', 'oceanwp' );
        } else {
            $text = __( 'Unavailable', 'oceanwp' );
        }  
    }
    
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'ocean_woo_outofstock_text', 'my_woo_outofstock_text', 20, 1 );
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin to great success: https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-stock-status/

You can create a global rule for a default stock message and also individual stock messages on each product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That part is working fine. I have it customised, but on all stock status i have "only 7 m2 left" because I sell tiles by m2, but in the few categories where it isn't m2, I would like to write "only 7 left" or "only 7 line-meters left"

Comment: The plugin I suggested does this as well. You can put the global stock status as "only %s m2 left" and then on the products that are not sold in m2 you can change the stock status *within* the product to "only 7 line-meters left" or whatever you wish. 

Each product can have its own unique stock message if that's what you desire